# Is there a command line program to lookup Scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Ruby has a program called ri where you can type in 'ri Array' and get its manpage. Is there something like that for scaladoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but it *would* be cool. I don't think it would be too hard to do it, given that scaladoc (I heard) is supposed to be kind of pluggable.

Comment: I'm thinking more like a command-line script that reuses the static HTML/JS artifacts already on disk, assuming the user has installed the doc bundle.  Either way, it'd be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the Scaladoc web "app" is being enhanced with indexes for fast in-browser search, this kind of thing should become much easier, especially now that there's always a JS interpreter in JDK6.  I'd suggest filing an [enhancement request](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala). :)

Comment: a command line app would be great because it'll allow easy lookup in vim/emacs.

Answer (score 1):

[vim-scaladoc](https://github.com/mdreves/vim-scaladoc) was released in late 2012.

Answer (score 0):

With a command-line browser like elinks, and just one directory which matches `scaladoc`, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
for link in $(locate scaladoc | grep $1); do elinks $link ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Stefan Zeiger's [Extradoc](https://github.com/szeiger/extradoc) would probably be a good basis for this and other documentation tools.