# How to run scala code on scala console start?

Tags: scala, configuration, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to run some scala code each time the scala console repl starts (this code has to change the REPL context)?

Was expecting there might be some `.scala` or similar config file which would allow setting that.

My use case is running this code on each REPL start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770870/750216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name := "scala-playground"
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
organization := "org.reactormonk"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "ScalaNLP Maven2" at "http://repo.scalanlp.org/repo",
  "Scala Tools Snapshots" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1",
  "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.1",
  "com.github.alexarchambault" %% "argonaut-shapeless_6.1" % "1.0.0-M1",
  "com.github.pathikrit"  %% "better-files-akka"  % "2.15.0"
)

javaOptions += "-Xmx4g"
addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector" % "0.7.1")
initialCommands in console := """
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
//import shapeless._
"""
```

Comment: Thank you, the initialCommands was what I was looking for: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Scala.html#Define+the+initial+commands+evaluated+when+entering+the+Scala+REPL

Comment: Where can I declare this so that it works globally, outside of any project?

Answer (score 1):

### When running with `sbt console`:

I created a `%USERPROFILE%\.sbt\0.13\global.sbt` global configuration file and added the start code to it:

```
initialCommands in console := """
    def viewdoc[A](a: A) {
    val name = a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass.getName
    val url = "http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#"+name
    val pb = new ProcessBuilder("firefox",url)
    val p = pb.start
    p.waitFor
    }
"""
```

Running sbt console:

```
C:\WINDOWS>sbt console
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to windows (in build file:/C:/Windows/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
viewdoc: [A](a: A)Unit
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_74).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

### When running with `scala`:

See question here: [Call another program with arguments passed to the currently executing batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313206/750216)