# Call another program with arguments passed to the currently executing batch file

Tags: scala, batch-file

My use case: having a repl executable `scala.bat` which takes some arguments, one of which allows pointing it to a configuration file which is ran on start. I renamed `scala.bat` to `scala-original.bat` and called `scala-original.bat` from inside `scala.bat`:

```
@echo off

scala-original.bat -i C:\Progra~2\scala\bin\test-config.scala
```

How can I pass the original arguments `scala.bat` was called with to `scala-original.bat`? They should be added at the end of:

```
scala-original.bat -i C:\Progra~2\scala\bin\test-config.scala
```

For example, calling:

```
scala.bat -nc
```

should run:

```
scala-original.bat -i C:\Progra~2\scala\bin\test-config.scala -nc
```

We can ignore double specifying the -i part again for now.

For my use case, using an alias could also be a solution as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/750216 , eg.:

```
@echo off
doskey scala=scala-original.bat -i C:\Progra~2\scala\bin\test-config.scala $*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%*` is "all parameters to me (the currently running batchfile)". (Try `echo %*` in a batchfile). That makes it very easy to pass them to the next batchfile:

```
scala-original.bat -i C:\Progra~2\scala\bin\test-config.scala %*
```